# Postar meu resultado do aplicativo no Facebook

Tags: android, facebook-sdk

Boa tarde... meu aplicativo é de acompanhar jogo de futebol... contendo numero de gols, quais times.... e quando clica em salvar ele mostra pra mim **time1 X time2 = 2 x 0** (exemplo) e queria por para compartilhar no facebook... cadastrei minha conta como desenvolvedor e no site deles, parece que so da para compartilhar dentro do app (Imagens, videos ou links) e eu queria compartilhar ja uma mensagem gravada como o exemplo a cima... o mesmo `String/int` que vai para listView vai para o facebook.

Como que faria isso, não conseguir achar na internet que possa me ajudar com essa opção

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nathan, você já tentou usar um Intent?

```
    String message = "Text I want to share.";
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("text/plain");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Title of the dialog the system will open"));
```

Ele vai abrir uma lista de aplicativos para compartilhar.

Comment: gostei dessa forma... me da outras opções, só que por exemplo escolho o facebook a mensagem não fica grava, quando abre ele aparece para eu escrever alguma coisa mas a mensagem não fica gravada, teria alguma ideia de me ajudar? Já o whatsApp funciona...